# Animating text after click on img

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I would like to ask for some tips how make my idea come true.
I wanted to animate text after clicking on img. By animating I meant something like Fade in or this stuff.

The black ones would be img and after clicking image 1 it would roll down column with text about it. Then the same in img 2 and 3 etc.

```css
.top {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
}
.text{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div class="top">a</div>
  <div class="top">b</div>
  <div class="top">c</div>
  <br>
  <div class="text">Test1</div>
  <div class="text">Test2</div>
  <div class="text">Test3</div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick version with jQuery, let me know if you need a vanilla version. :)

```js
$('.hook').on('click', function( evt ) {
 $(evt.currentTarget).find('.text').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.hook{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hook">
  <div class="image">a</div>
  <div class="text" style="display: none;">Test1</div>
</div>
<div class="hook">
  <div class="image">a</div>
  <div class="text" style="display: none;">Test2</div>
</div>
<div class="hook">
  <div class="image">a</div>
  <div class="text" style="display: none;">Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to contact you..Would you give me please your email or something? I tried the links  on your profile but it always redirected me to 404

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```js
// Declare your elements
var top_divs = document.querySelectorAll('.top'),
  text_divs = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

// For each ".top"
for (var i = 0; i < top_divs.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    // When you click on it
    top_divs[index].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Toggle the ".shown" class on the corresponding ".text"
      toggleClass(text_divs[index], 'shown');
    });
  })(i);
}

// Code from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
function toggleClass(el, cl) {
  if (el.className.split(' ').indexOf(cl) > -1) {
    el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + cl.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
  } else {
    el.className += ' ' + cl;
  }
}
```

```css
.top {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  /* Makes them transparent by default */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Make their opacity animate when it changes */
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

/* Show them when they have the class */
.text.shown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on one of these:</p>
<div class="top">a</div>
<div class="top">b</div>
<div class="top">c</div>
<br>
<div class="text">Test1</div>
<div class="text">Test2</div>
<div class="text">Test3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('div.top').each(function(index, img){
  jQuery(img).click(slide.bind({index: index}));
});


function slide() {
  jQuery('div.text:eq('+ this.index +')').slideToggle();
}
```

```css
.item{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.top {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="top">a</div>
 <div class="text">Test1</div>
  </div>
<div class="item">
   <div class="top">b</div>
  <div class="text">Test2</div>
 </div>
<div class="item">
   <div class="top">c</div>
 <div class="text">Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for code, it works, but I am marking @Win answer because it´s closer to my idea..